# Create static attribute of class (attribute is instance of that same class)

Tags: python, oop, static

Let's say I have a class defined as follow :

```
class Foo():
   baz = None
   def __init__(self, bar):
       self.bar = bar
```

Now, in that example `Foo.baz` is `None`. Now let's say that this class attribute needs to be an instance of `Foo` like below:

```
class Foo():
    baz = Foo("baz")
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

How would I proceed?

Similarly, is there any way to create a "class property". I know I can assign a lambda function returning a new instance of the class to a class attribute, but I'd rather not have to write the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the line `baz = Foo("baz")` inside a class even before defining `Foo` earlier; it's not possible ie Python will throw a `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined` at you, but here's a workaround to achieve what you intend:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, bar):
       self.bar = bar
Foo.baz=Foo('foo')
```

Now `Foo.baz` is an instance of the `Foo` class and also `baz` is a class attribute of the `Foo` class and hence will be inherited by all instances of the class as well:

```
myFoo = Foo('myFoo')
```

You can verify that `myFoo.baz.bar` is infact `'foo'` and not `'myFoo'`

```
print(myFoo.bar) 
# myFoo
print(myFoo.baz.bar)
# foo
```

Also note that this will cause `Foo.baz`, `Foo.baz.baz`, `Foo.baz.baz.baz` etc. all to be a `Foo` object because `Foo.baz` has value `Foo('foo')` ie an object of `Foo` class and `baz` is also a class attribute of `Foo`.